# Page Time Intervals Refresh

Tags: php, html, sql, curl

```
$output_filename = "work.txt";

    $host = "http://www.indeed.com/l-Cuyahoga-Falls,-Ohio-jobs.html";
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $host);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    $result = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    print_r($result); // prints the contents of the collected file before writing..

    // the following lines write the contents to a file in the same directory (provided permissions etc)
    $fp = fopen($output_filename, 'w');
    fwrite($fp, $result);
    fclose($fp);
```

It creates a file within the directory you upload the script to. And then it displays the data within the file. But I am having a hard time trying to automatically refresh intervals. I need it to automatically update itself.

How can I make the entire page download? A lot of the images sometimes don't show up all the way when i run the script. Is it the website thats causing that?

Comment: why not to create a cron file and then get the results, or use ajax for that

Comment: If the image URLs are relative URLs, they'll be interpreted by the browser relative to the URL of your page, not the site you're pulling from.

Comment: Thanks guys for the help! - Yeah, I am trying to figure this out. Is there a way to automatically refresh the page without having to upload the file all the time to the server? Can something like this be done? New with CURL.